# how to convert png in mac format to window format

Tags: image-processing, png

I have some png files
I can see those in mac os, but can not see in win os.
I want to convert these images for window os.
How to convert?
Or I want to get converter for this purpose.
Thank you.

Comment: PNG itself is platform independent, something else is wrong with your files.

Comment: Flomei is spot on.  Not only are PNG images platform independent... but almost **all** images are platform independent.  Images are ubiquitous - social media websites, e-mail, etc.  It wouldn't make sense to restrict images to be on a single platform when multiple people use a variety of different platforms to share information.  Making images only platform specific would hinder the sharing of information and a lot of things simply wouldn't work.

Comment: you can test it. please extract png files from any ipa file. then you cant see  the contents of image but can see in mac. ipa is zip file. you can change extension to zip and can open it

Comment: @DerfullWon - That doesn't make any sense sorry.

Comment: Short: PNG files inside an .ipa file may not actually be valid PNGs per [the official specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/). See my own [pngdefry ‒ Repairing -iPhone fried PNGs](http://www.jongware.com/pngdefry.html) for the longer version.

Answer (score 0):

I open the png images (those from ipa) in photoshop (on mac) and then save the psd or simply save the images to png again. and then can easily open them back on windows.